# Java/Android: How to send packets, while receive packets on arrival

Tags: java, android, networking, udp, nio

the question is I'm using a single thread with DatagramChannel to send data to a server with a specific rate. While sending, the server will sent a rate info about every 5 second(approximately).
How can I get this rate info packet as soon as it arrives, and get the string info from this packet, print it out with a function I defined in the main class.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are sending at a particular rate which means that you are sleeping between operations.  A sleeping thread cannot also be looking for the response.  You will need to spawn a thread that listens for the rate packet and records the rate somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need one thread for receiving and one thread for sending.  To do both at once in one thread will make your code unnecessarily complex.